# Load 2nd drop down list items based on 1st selected drop down list item

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
                   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <label for="ddl1">1:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" name="ddl1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"  />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <label for="ddl2">1:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" name="ddl2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" required />
                    </div>
```

I'm trying to get the drop down list items of ddl2 based off the values of ddl1 that I've selected. Thus the "if" function & the void Get1 & Get2.
Note: the datas of each ddl will come from a table in my database.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddl1Get();
        Get1();
        Get2();
    }

    #region "Function"
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
        Get1();
    }
    else if (1.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
    {
        Get2();
    }
    #endregion
}

    #region "Function"
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
        Get1();
    }
    else if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
    {
        Get2();
    }
 #endregion

 void Get1()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Category FROM Table1";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddl2.DataSource = dr;
    ddl2.DataTextField = "Category";
    ddl2.DataValueField = "Category";
    ddl2.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", ""));
}

void Get2()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Category FROM Table2";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddl2.DataSource = dr;
    ddl2.DataTextField = "Category";
    ddl2.DataValueField = "Category";
    ddl2.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", ""));
} 
void ddlGet()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Category FROM Table0";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddl1.DataSource = dr;
    ddl1.DataTextField = "Category";
    ddl1.DataValueField = "Category";
    ddl1.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", ""));
}

protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
        Get1();
    }
    else if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
    {
        Get2();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your Page_Load event look like.. this is where you should be checking things like IsPostBack etc.. have you even attempted to step through the code using the debugger..? also I would think that your second dropdown in the Select query, one would expect to see a Where Clause...

Comment: also why are you showing us `void Get2()` method twice is that a mistake in your code that you pasted..?

Comment: @MethodMan my bad, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

There is selectedindexchanged for dropdown..just double click on dropdown and copy your code inside it. then it should work fine.

```
public void ddl1_selectedIndexChanged(sender,e){ //your code here }
```

Also you have mentioned Get2() twice in your code . is it a copy mistake or you didnt notice your code? That might the issue why you are getting same values binded even though selected value is changed

Comment: My bad, I've corrected it now. but still does not work. also edited the codes. added pageload and indexchanged.

Comment: set AutoPostBack="true" for ddl1 and try

Answer (score 0):

use `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of `asp:DropDownList`

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
  {
    Get1();
  }
  else if (ddl1.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
  {
    Get2();
  }
}
```

Also :

```
  ddl1.DataTextField = "Category";
  ddl1.DataValueField = "ID";
```